# Scala Parallel Collections class cast

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing

I am doing some prototyping and I need a quick way to speed up some algorithm. So I was looking at Scala Parallel Collections. Without going into the details of why I need to use `foreach`, can someone shed light on why the following crashes (just an example):

```
List(1,2,3,4).combinations(2).asParIterable.foreach(_ => println("foo"))

java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.SeqLike$CombinationsItr cannot be 
  cast to scala.collection.parallel.ParIterable
at scala.collection.parallel.package$$anon$2.asParIterable(package.scala:70)
```

(Scala is 2.10.3)

---

Or in other words: How can I parallelize an iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parallelize an iterator; you can turn it into an iterable and parallelize *that*:

```
List(1,2,3,4).combinations(2).toSeq.par.foreach(_ => println("foo"))
```

I am not sure if `toIterable` instead of `toSeq` will work as well. However, if you only need `foreach`,

```
iterator.foreach(_ => Future(println("foo")))
```

should work.

Comment: Ok thanks that works, also `toParArray`. I was hoping that I don't need to keep all the permutations (which can be a lot in my actual case) in memory, but no `OutOfMemoryError` yet...